# Struggling with Lambda expression (VB .net)

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, left-join, code-first, linq-expressions

I have a relatively simple thing that I can do easily in SQL, but I'm trying to get used to using Lambda expressions, and having a hard time.

Here is a simple example. Basically I have 2 tables.

- tblAction (ActionID, ActionName)
- tblAudit (AuditID, ActionID, Deleted)

tblAudit may have an entry regarding tblAction with the Deleted flag set to 1.

All I want to do is select actions where we don't have a Deleted entry in tblAudit. So the SQL statement is:

```
Select tblAction.* 
From tblAction LEFT JOIN tblAudit on tblAction.ActionID=tblAudit.ActionID
where tblAudit.Deleted <> 1
```

What would be the equivalent of the above in VB.Net's LINQ? I tried:

```
Context.Actions.Where(Function(act) Context.Audit
.Where(Function(aud) aud.Deleted=False AndAlso aud.ActionID=act.ActionID)).ToList
```

But that is really an inner join type scenario where it requires that each entry in tblAction also has an Entry in tblAudit. I am using Entity Framework Code First to do the database mapping. Is there a way to define the mapping in a way where you can do this?

Comment: I'm not clear what lambda expressions have to do with this.  Perhaps you mean [Linq?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088)

Comment: Razi, check out [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and [101 LINQ Samples in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088).

Comment: Group Join will do outer join. A navigation property (Action.Audits) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

`Public Property Audits As DbSet<Audit>`

into your action entity class (to register the association between those tables).

Now you can just write what you mean:

`(From act in Context.Actions Where Not act.Audits.Any(Function(audit)  audit.Deleted)).ToArray`

which is equivalent to

`Context.Actions.Where(Function(act) Not act.Audits.Any(Function(audit) audit.Deleted)).ToArray`

and let the LINQ parser do the hard SQL work.